# Example.com returning 502

Tags: http, https

This is a bit odd.  `example.com` is failing the IP lookup, but other websites are fine.

```
GET http://www.example.com/
502 Fiddler - DNS Lookup Failed (text/html)

GET https://www.bbc.co.uk/
200 OK (text/html)
```

I'm not using a proxy, I'm using a domestic ISP so no corporate restrictions.

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Check Your Dns Settings, Maybe Try 1.1.1.1 as a DNS Server

Comment: `1.1.1.1` seems to be an advert for a CloudFlare _thing_, some sort of proxy that converts HTTP with a proprietary protocol.

Comment: DNS-over-HTTPS or DNS-over-TLS is still DNS though. Proxy is Completely Unrelated.   (Domain Name System) is the phone book. A proxy server is a server where connections/requests are being made to instead of to the final destinations. If they can't resolve an address. High likelyhood of it being a DNS Issue.

Answer (score 0):

check a cloudflare protected website first. or https://www.cloudflare.com/.

check your results. > else try a user ip script on the header > then try again.

```
    <? echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?>
```